# пишу телеграмм бота на aiogram , и хотел бы как пользователь добавлять данные (например chat id в массив ) через команду / chat id (и сам id)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

пробовал через for i in range  но проблема как в коде указать команду проверки на на сообщение ведь chat id  у всех разный

Comment: чистый, как воздух Гренландии поток мыслей... уф

Answer (score 0):

допустим у вас команда /chat_id 123, сделайте хендлер на данную команду, а потом `message.text.split(' ')[-1]` чтобы добраться до этого параметра